# Eclipse RCP Application could not start

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to learn eclipse RCP and am following a tutorial to try and learn the basics but for some reason my application won't start!

I've read the error log but I can't make heads or tails of it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? These are the errors I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: My suggestion is to start over with one of the default prototype RCP applications.  Carefully make one change at a time, testing your RCP application after each change.  When it breaks again, you'll know which change broke your RCP.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gilbert but I was getting the error straight after I created a default application having changed nothing. After a bit of research I found a fix to it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I found it was down to some missing plug-ins and I found a quick fix to fill in the missing plug-ins.

Right click on your product configuration file -> Run as -> Run Configurations...

In this menu go to the Plug-ins tab and check the check box "Validate plug-ins automatically prior to launch" and hit the button "Add Required Plug-ins".

This added all the required plug-ins that I was missing :)